# Given a distance function $d$ prove it is a metric on the Baire space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Given a distance function $d$ prove it is a metric on the Baire space:

Baire space is defined as : the set $\mathbb{N}\backslash \{0\}$ of all sequences valued in $\mathbb{N}\backslash \{0\}$

Define $d((x_n), (y_n)) := \Bigg\{ \begin{array} \,0 \,\,if\,\,(x_n)=(y_n) \\ \, 2^{-min\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid x_n \neq y_n \}} \end{array}  , (x_n), (y_n):$ sequences valued in the Baire space.

1) $d(a,b) \ge 0 \\$ Let $(x_n), (y_n)$ be sequences in the Baire space. 
         case i) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies d((x_n), (y_n)) = 0 $ case ii) $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} (n \ge 0)((x_{n_0})\neq(y_{n_0})) \implies d((x_n), (y_n)) = \frac{1}{2^{n_0}} \ge 0 \,\, $ and from the definition the defined 'distance' is zero iff the two sequences are equal. $\checkmark$

2) Symmetry : i) if $\forall n \mathbb{N} ((x_n) = (y_n)) \implies (y_n)= (x_n)$ since equality is computed component wise in a sequence, namely, $(x_n) = (y_n) \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall i,j \in I (i = j \implies x_{n_i} = y_{n_j}) \iff (y_n) = (x_n) \implies d((x_n), (y_n)) = d((y_n), (x_n))$

3)Triangle Inequality : Let $(x_n), (y_n), (z_n)$ be sequences in the Baire space. If they are all equal then nothing to prove as $0 \le 0+0$ Further if $(x_n) = (y_n)$ then still holds as $0 \le$ all possible 'distance' values. Assume  $d((x_n)(y_n)) \neq 0$ and $(z_n) \neq (y_n) \,\text{or}\, (x_n)$,$\displaystyle d((x_n), (y_n)) = \frac{1}{2^{min\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid (x_n)\neq(y_n)\}}} \le \frac{1}{2^{min\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid (x_n)\neq(z_n)\}}} + \frac{1}{2^{min\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid (z_n)\neq(y_n)\}}}$ let $n_i, n_j$ be the min $n$ for each denominator in the preceding sum respectively. we get $\displaystyle \frac{2^{n_i}+2^{n_j}}{2^{n_i}\cdot2^{n_j}} \ge \frac{1}{2^{min \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid (x_n) \neq (y_n)\}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments for the first two properties are correct, if a little wordy. For the triangle inequality I suggest the following approach.

Let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$. If $x\ne y$, define

$$\delta(x,y)=\min\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:x_n\ne y_n\}\;,$$

so that $d(x,y)=2^{-\delta(x,y)}$.

Now let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, and $z=\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$. You’ve already observed that $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ if $x=y$, $x=z$, or $z=y$, so we may assume that all three points are distinct.

- Show that $\delta(x,y)\ge\min\{\delta(x,z),\delta(z,y)\}$.
- Conclude that $d(x,y)\le\max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}$.

Note that for all real numbers $\alpha,\beta\ge 0$ it’s true that $\max\{\alpha,\beta\}\le\alpha+\beta$, so we automatically get the triangle inequality

$$d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)\;.$$

In fact

$$d(x,y)\le\max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}$$

is known as the *strong triangle inequality*, and metrics that satisfy it are called [*non-Archimedean metrics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) or *ultrametrics*. They are exceptionally easy to work with in some contexts.